# Form fields need to show horizontally in joomla 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to show the fields side by side in Joomla 3.6.5 front end.In this component for the particular view some form fields are dynamic fields. so i'm not using renderField() method.Here is the expected view

Path: components/compoent_name/views/viewname/tmpl/default.php

```
   <form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="POST" name="adminForm" id="adminForm" 
    onSubmit="return formValidation()"  class="form-horizontal form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style='float:left'><h2></h2></div>
    <div class='form-container'>
    <div class='span6'>
    <div>
    <span> Hi Welcome to the </span>
    <select  required="true" id="adname_id" name="adname_id" >
    <option  value="company1">company1</option>
    <option  value="company2">company2</option></select>
    <span> Enter date</span><input type="text"  required="true" id="discount_date" name="discount_date"/>
    <span> Enter price</span>
    <input type="text" required="true" id="enter_price" name="enter_price" />
    <span>Thanks</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Help me to achieve this

[image]

Comment: Set input and select elements to "display:inline-block;"  I think bootstrap will set them to block, which will cause them to each be on a new line. You could possibly also add the 'pull-left' class to them all as this will give them "float:left"